# Actualizar progress-bar

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, angular8

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Necesito imprimir una progress-bar de Bootstrap cuyo ancho debería cambiar según lo que dice el número de porcentaje que indique la base de datos. (sé que luego debo realizar consultas programadas por tiempo, eso lo tengo resuelto), pero no encuentro la forma de concatenar en los estilos la variable que indica el ancho. 
Yo recibo los datos desde el back-end y necesito procesarlo en el front, por lo la solución de concatenar variable de php no me sirve (como lo vi en otros posteos).
Les adjunto los códigos que creo que servirán para la ayuda.

```
    import { Component, OnInit }                       from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params}                 from '@angular/router';
    import { User }                                                  from '../../models/user';
    import { UserService }                             from '../../services/user.service';
    import { NpiService }       from '../../services/npi.service';
    import{Npi}                 from '../../models/npi'; 


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-npi-list',
      templateUrl: './npi-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./npi-list.component.css']
    })
    export class NpiListComponent implements OnInit {
      public title: string; 
      public Npis:any; 
      sortedManifiesto: Npi[];



      constructor(
        private _route:              ActivatedRoute,
        private _router:             Router,
        private _npiService:         NpiService,
        private _userService:        UserService,
      ) {
        this.title='Listado de NPI'; 
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this._npiService.listarNpi().subscribe(
          response=>{
            if(response.status=='success'){
              console.log(response);
              this.Npis=response.npi;
              console.log(this.Npis);
            }
          },
          error=>{
           console.log(<any>error);
          }
       );
     }
  }
}
```

el objeto npi, tiene un campo npi.progreso que es el que quiero insertar como ancho portentual del estilo. Aqui va el html.

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4 class="mt-5" style="background: rgb(59, 71, 244); color: white; text-align: center;">{{title}}</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterManifiesto" placeholder="Buscar..." [(ngModel)]="filterManifiesto">
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="container-fluid col-10">


                        <div *ngIf=!sortedNpi>
                            <table matSort (matSortChange)="sortNpi($event)" class="table table-hover table-tripped mt-5" id="cars-list">
                                <tr>

                                    <th mat-sort-header='producto'> Producto</th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='cliente'> Cliente </th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='linea'> Línea de Producción </th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='tipo_producto'> Tipo de Producto </th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='fecha_objetivo'> Fecha Objetivo </th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='status'> Estado </th>
                                    <th>Progreso </th>

                                    <th mat-sort-header='usuario'> Creado Por </th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header='created_at'> Fecha de creación </th>



                                </tr>


                                <tr *ngFor="let npi of Npis | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 100, currentPage: pActual } ">

                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.producto}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.cliente}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.linea}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.tipo_producto}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.fecha_objetivo}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td *ngIf='npi.status==0'>
                                        <span class="badge" style="background:rgb(130, 10, 229); color: #fff">Comenzado</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td *ngIf='npi.status==1'>
                                        <span class="badge badge-dark">Finalizado</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-2">
                                        <div class="progress">
                                            {{npi.progreso}}

                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success progreso-npi" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                            <!-- este ejemplo es 25%, yo quiero poner la variable npi.progreso aquí -> style= "width: npi.progreso%" -->
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.user.name}} {{npi.user.surname}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{npi.created_at}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td *ngIf="npi.status==1">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;">Ver</button>
                                    </td>

                                    <td *ngIf="npi.status==0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-warning">Continuar</button>
                                    </td>


                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pActual = $event"></pagination-controls>
            </div>
```

dentro de tabla, el  es el elmento html en cuestión, por favor ignoren la parte del código que no corresponde a la consulta.

Espero que se entienda la consulta y que puedan ayudarme. Cordiales Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El valor cambiante lo tienes que poner de esta manera `[style.width.%]="porcentaje"` donde `porcentaje` corresponde al valor de `npi.progreso`

Quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success progreso-npi" 
     role="progressbar" 
     [style.width.%]="npi.progreso"
     aria-valuenow="25" 
     aria-valuemin="0" 
     aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
```

Mas información [aquí](http://The%20target%20of%20a%20data-binding%20is%20something%20in%20the%20DOM.)

Comment: Muchísima Gracias!!. Funcionó Perfecto. No creí que fuera tan sencillo, pero...había que saberlo. Muy agradecido!.